# Need help opening a link in a new tab from drop down menu

Tags: html

```
<select id="select" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value 
&amp;&amp; (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Choose your state</option>
<option value="http://www.treasury.state.al.us/Content/index.aspx">Alabama</option>
<option value="http://treasury.dor.alaska.gov/">Alaska</option>
```

I've tried looking at other examples, but I'm not sure where to add the "_blank" target attribute to this code to let the link open in a new window/tab. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, so it looks like I use a window.open (url) code. Where would that be placed?

Sorry, I'm a total noob to this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the window.open function instead of the window.location variable. Window.location is meant to redirect the document itself. Window.open opens a new window.

Try `window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)` instead.

```
<select id="select" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Choose your state</option>
<option value="http://www.treasury.state.al.us/Content/index.aspx">Alabama</option>
<option value="http://treasury.dor.alaska.gov/">Alaska</option>
</select>
```

Comment: _blank is the default target for window.open, so no need to specify it

Comment: this will open a new window with the existing page if they return and choose "choose your state"

Comment: @mlplungjan You are correct, even better would be to call a custom function which does some input validation first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select id="select" onchange="var win = window.open(this.value, '_blank');win.focus();">
<option value="">Choose your state</option>
<option value="http://www.treasury.state.al.us/Content/index.aspx">Alabama</option>
<option value="http://treasury.dor.alaska.gov/">Alaska</option>
</select>
```

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/28cLcusn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try window.open which may be blocked. Also test you have a value.

```
onchange="var href = this.value; if (href) window.open(href,'_blank');"
```

Comment: _blank is the default target for window.open, so no need to specify it

Comment: I specify it because some browsers want a window name and I want to show whoever sees the code that I specifically want _blank. I do not trust w3schools. Mdn does not mention default window name